# List<> overwrite value with old list

Tags: c#, list

I have this code:

```
List<List<string>> strs = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> str = new List<string>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow sr in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    if(i >= 10)
    {
        strs.Add(str); //Here strs have one str with 10 values
        str.Clear();
        i = 0;
        var a = strs; //Here strs have one str with 0 values
    }
    str.Add(sr.Cells["MOBILNI"].Value.ToString().Trim());
    i++;
}
strs.Add(str);
```

I have list of `strings` which i populate and when it reach 10 members i put whole list into list of `List<string>`, then clear list of `strings` to populate it with next 10 of items. Problem is that when list of `strings` reach 10 members, i add it to list of `List<string>` and in debugging i see my `strs` has 1 member (`List<string>`) which has 10 elements (10 strings) but when i clear my base list of `strings` it also clears that list inside `List<List<string>>`.

When i use `str = new List<string>()` instead of `str.Clear()` it works normally.

So why is this happening and how to overcome it?

Comment: When you do this: `var a = strs;` You're declaring a variable that immediately goes out of scope. So this line isn't doing anything. It's declared within the `if` block, so it doesn't exist outside of that block.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  What is the point of putting your 10-element list into another list?

What's happening is that your 10-element list only exists once.  When you put it into the other list, you're just putting a reference to it.

Comment: It is not doing anything, it was just for testing purpose so i can see values of `strs` in debugger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `strs.Add(str)` you add the exact same instance if `List<string>` to your list of lists, that you clear afterwards. Calling `str.Clear` will thus be reflected in all references to that instance, also in `strs[0]`, `strs[1]` and so on. This happens because a `List<T>` is a [reference-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). Doing anything with one reference will be reflected in all references. Value-types on the other hand will copy the entire object whenever you pass it to a method. Thus the following code will resulst in `i` having the value `4` after calling `DoSomething`.

```
int i = 4;
var result = DoSomething(i);

void DoSomething(int j)
{
    j = -7;
}
```

To circumvent this, you´d have to create a completely new list, instead of just adding the existing one:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow sr in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    if(i >= 10)
    {
        strs.Add(new List<string>(str));
        str.Clear();
        i = 0;
        var a = strs; //Here strs have one str with 0 values
    }
    str.Add(sr.Cells["MOBILNI"].Value.ToString().Trim());
    i++;
}
strs.Add(str);
```

Comment: If this (great) answer confuses you, make sure you understand that Lists are reference types - and what that implies.

Comment: Yea thank you @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi that is what i needed. Answer explains something but now you mentioned it i have full picture of it. I will accept this answer in 4 min.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a copy of the original list before clearing, so you can use `.ToList`

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow sr in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    if(i >= 10)
    {
        strs.Add(str.ToList()); //Here strs have one str with 10 values
        str.Clear();
        i = 0;
        var a = strs; //Here strs have one str with 0 values
    }
    str.Add(sr.Cells["MOBILNI"].Value.ToString().Trim());
    i++;
}
strs.Add(str);
```

Your other option is, instead of clearing it, set str to a brand new list:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow sr in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    if(i >= 10)
    {
        strs.Add(str); //Here strs have one str with 10 values
        str = new List<string>();
        i = 0;
        var a = strs; //Here strs have one str with 0 values
    }
    str.Add(sr.Cells["MOBILNI"].Value.ToString().Trim());
    i++;
}
strs.Add(str);
```

Comment: Creating a new list instead of calling `Clear` is a great idea. +1

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the `List<string>` to `List<List<string>>` you are actually just passing the pointer (reference) of `List<string>`, not the whole object. Thats why when you call `str.clear()`, it clears the list object, to which the pointer in `List<List<string>>` is pointing to. Instead of calling `clear()` you should create a new object (`str = new List<string>();`) or `clone()` the object when adding it to the `List<List<string>>`.